# Javascript indexOf not finding text in a variable

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am sure there is something simple that I am missing but I am stumped here.

The issue is that I am looping through an array of strings and using the string value to search for a part of that string using indexOf. The first time around the loop the index of is finding what I am looking for but the second time it is not.

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jeremywrags/uSwjG/1/

the line that seems to be not working is this

```
var aliasIndex = fromclause.indexOf(" " + tableAlias + " " );
```

I am trying to build a SQL parser for a cloud app and the use case here is that when a table is aliased I need to get the original table name so that I can look up the table columns. The first time around the loop index of returns the index and then the table name. The second time around the index of is -1 and the table name is not retrieved.

If I need to provide more context please let me know.

thanks

Comment: Put the content of `fromclause` **in** the question, not hidden away in the fiddle. Links (even fiddles) can rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: You know that you can also give TABLES aliases by using the `as` and not just columns ? that will break your code.

Comment: Consider looking for a real SQL parser, rather than messing around with strings in this way?

Comment: Change your array initialiser to `arr = fields.split(", ");` (with the extra space) and it will work as you expected it to.

Comment: Hi Orel, I know, I am trying to tackle one thing at a time...

Comment: Ismail, do you know of one?

Answer (score 0):

It's not matching because on the second pass, `tableAlias` is the string `" b"` (note the space). So then you search for `"  b "` (note two leading spaces), which isn't there.

Rather than using `alert`, use the debugger built into your browser. You can set breakpoints in the code, step through line by line, inspect variables, etc., etc. Doing that with this would have shown you, when looking at the variable `tableAlias`, that it had a leading space, hopefully helping you find the solution.

Here's what that looks like in Chrome's debugger, for instance:

[image: Example of debugging]

(If you look at the jsFiddle source above the actual debugger's version, you'll see a `debugger;` statement in the code — normally you don't need that statement, you can just open your page, use the "Sources" tab to find your JavaScript file, navigate to the line, and click the margin to the left of it to set a breakpoint. But sometimes [for instance, when using jsFiddle], the `debugger;` statement is handy. What it does is, if the debugger is open, halts execution of the code at that point like a breakpoint does.)